# Computer feels laggy running Linux but okay with Windows 10 don't know why?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, cpu, lag

- Processor: AMD A8-6600K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 3.90 GHz
- Installed RAM: 8.00 GB (7.20 GB usable)
- System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- Pen and touch: No pen or touch input is available for this display
- HARD DISK DRIVE: TOSHIBA(every os uses the same hard disk with the same amount of partition)

This is my computers specification. Now my question is when run Windows 10 on my computer it is literally faster(performance, dragging an application, startup of an application etc.) than running Linux (arch base{KDE PLASMA}, Debian base tried{KDE PLASMA}).

I don't know why it happens, but it really annoys me because I know linux should run faster on my PC as it consumes less RAM and moreover the desktop is blurry too in Linux rather than Windows. Will ubuntu give me more better performance than arch or debian?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a modern Linux kernel, chances are that it is patched against several Intel and AMD bugs that allow, **very** approximately speaking, guessing the content of protected memory by timing the CPU while *thinking* about accessing it ("legal" reads and "forbidden" reads, so to speak, take different times), in different ways (yes, "Intel bug" may mean [AMD too](https://www.amd.com/system/files/documents/technical-guidance-for-mitigating-branch-type-confusion_v7_20220712.pdf)).

The second most radical solution is to ensure that instructions take the same time regardless; since you can't speed up already optimized code, you slow down the rest.

Windows did the same thing, then undid that when they noticed the same pattern and concluded that, anyway, Windows 10 is only ever going to run in a "personal" environment, where processes are all ultimately owned by the same guy.

**IF** that is the case, then on a very modern kernel you can do the same by adding this one instruction to the GRUB bootloader:

```
mitigations=off
```

It's worth a try. For slightly older kernels you have to check what parameters are needed. There are [several pages](https://linuxreviews.org/HOWTO_make_Linux_run_blazing_fast_(again)_on_Intel_CPUs) out there; most are very Intel-specific, but some cover AMD too. And some flags work on both because they leverage the exact same mechanism anyway.

Otherwise, you'd need to run a benchmark to see **what** exactly is going slow: is it really the CPU? Might it not be, say, the RAM? The drive? Networking? Something else? - and then you can search for *that*.

## Addendum

> moreover the desktop is blurry

That has nothing to do with kernel or CPU, that is the monitor resolution (and maybe frequency also) that aren't up to spec. Read the specs off the manual, or the Windows configuration page, and replicate them in Linux. Linux generally offers you more control, but you can start by cloning the Windows setup.